# MongoDB aggregation - grouping by distinct pairs

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I need to group records from the certain collection by unordered distinct pairs of fields (`sender` and `recipient`) with PyMongo driver.
For example pairs *(sender_field_value, recipient_field_value)* and *(recipient_field_value, sender_field_value)* are considered to be equal.

My aggregation pipeline

```
groups = base.flow.records.aggregate([
    {'$match': {'$or': [
                {'sender': _id},
                {'recipient': _id}
            ]
        }
    },
    {'$group': {
            '_id': {
                'sender': '$sender',
                'recipient': '$recipient',
            }, 
            'data_id': {
                '$max': '$_id'
            }
        }
    },            
    {'$limit': 20}
])
```

applied to the data

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("533950ca9c3b6222569520c2"), "recipient" : ObjectId("533950ca9c3b6222569520c1"), "sender" : ObjectId("533950ca9c3b6222569520c0") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("533950ca9c3b6222569520c4"), "recipient" : ObjectId("533950ca9c3b6222569520c0"), "sender" : ObjectId("533950ca9c3b6222569520c1") }
```

produces the following

```
{'ok': 1.0,
 'result': [
    {'_id': {'recipient': ObjectId('533950ca9c3b6222569520c0'), 'sender': ObjectId('533950ca9c3b6222569520c1')},
     'data_id': ObjectId('533950ca9c3b6222569520c4')},
    {'_id': {'recipient': ObjectId('533950ca9c3b6222569520c1'), 'sender': ObjectId('533950ca9c3b6222569520c0')},
     'data_id': ObjectId('533950ca9c3b6222569520c2')}
  ]
}
```

but the desired result is just

```
{'ok': 1.0,
 'result': [
    {'_id': {'recipient': ObjectId('533950ca9c3b6222569520c0'), 'sender': ObjectId('533950ca9c3b6222569520c1')},
     'data_id': ObjectId('533950ca9c3b6222569520c4')}
  ]
}
```

What would be the proper pipeline?

Comment: Perhaps show the data that is supposed to reduce to this result.

Comment: @NeilLunn updated, but I guess it's too small to be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick for achieving the distinct pair grouping is by passing to the $group _id the same 'thing' for either cases. I'll use a normal comparison to do that (you can come up with something different that better suits your case - if your sender and recipient are not directly comparable my solution does not work):

```
{$project : {
    "_id" : 1,
    "groupId" : {"$cond" : [{"$gt" : ['$sender', '$recipient']}, {big : "$sender", small : "$recipient"}, {big : "$recipient", small : "$sender"}]}
}},
{$group: {
    '_id': "$groupId",
    'data_id': {
        '$max': '$_id'
    }
}}
```

The complete aggregation pipeline would look like:

```
{$match : {
    '$or': [{'sender': userId},{'recipient': userId}]
}},
{$project : {
    "_id" : 1,
    "groupId" : {"$cond" : [{"$gt" : ['$sender', '$recipient']}, {big : "$sender", small : "$recipient"}, {big : "$recipient", small : "$sender"}]}
}},
{$group: {
    '_id': "$groupId",
    'data_id': {
        '$max': '$_id'
    }
}},
{$limit: 20}
```

Comment: That's pretty smart. Thanks.